# Importing the same module twice throws ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, vue.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm pretty new to Javascript and have to maintain this grown application. I implemented a new feature and tested it manually successfully (application builds in dev and prod mode successfully).
But when I run the tests, using `vue-cli-service test:unit` (mocha + chai), a runtime exception is thrown stating:

```
Exception occurred while loading your tests`
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'serviceBase' before initialization
```

`serviceBase.json`:

```js
import api from "./api";
import store from "./../store";
import i18n from "../../plugins/i18n";

export const serviceBase = {
  api: api,
  resource: "",
  preList: "me",
  preListOption: {
    getList: true
  },
{.....}
```

which is used in multiple places, one is `documentImageService.js`:

```js
import { createErrorMessage, serviceBase, clearance } from "../service";
import api from "../api";
import axios from "axios";

const DocumentImage = {
  ...serviceBase,
  clearance,
{.....}
```

Now, this const DocumentImage is used in two places. One is `renderer.js`

```js
import * as HB from "handlebars";
import { Helpers } from "@lextira/lexgate-document-renderer";
import DocumentImage from "@/store/utils/services/documentImageService.js";

export default class {
  /** @type {HB} */
  handlebars = undefined;
  /** @type {string} */
  clearanceToken = undefined;
{.....}
```

If I remove the import of DocumentImage here, the tests run without further issue. The `renderer.js` does not yet have a test, as this is part of the newly implemented feature.
However, as already said in the intro, when using the browser as runtime, everything including this renderer works fine. But this `import DocumentImage` seems to break the "test runtime".

I guess it has something to do with the configuration of the mocha runtime, but I couldn't find out from existing documentation where to look for the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a circular dependency in the end. Even if i didn't belive in it for most of the time.

`DocumentImageStore` → `DocumentImageService` → `ServiceBase` → `NotificationStore`.

As `DocumentImageStore` and `NotificationStore` resolve from the same vuex-store, in some case the dependency seems not to get resolved, while in other it does (I guess depending on which gets asked for first).

I resolved it by creating a lazy import for the `NotificationStore` in the Service:

```js
const getStore = () => import("./../store");

export const createNotification = function(message) {
  getStore().then(store => {
    store.default.dispatch("notificationStore/createNotification", message)
  });
}
```

I guess best would be to resolve the circular dependency completely, but at the current point I don't see how to do this the way it's implemented right now.